# How to append the jquery code on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had written a jquery code to auto refresh the messages in the chat box. But when I try to read old messages in the chat box, it doesn't allow since the chat division gets refresh for every 1 sec and get back to the fresh messages. I want to append this refresh property when I scroll for the old messages.

below is the jquery code.

```
setInterval(function(){ $('#messagesBody').load("get-messages.php? 
  employee_id="+employee_id);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: What does `append this refresh property when I scroll for the old messages.` mean?

Comment: the refresh property i.e loading of a part of page. this will gets refresh the chat box and  does'nt allow to read old messages within the chat box

Comment: What about sending the messages including an ID as JSON, when you receive the message you request only the messages with a higher ID and append them. You are currently downloading all chat messages every second?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

You should store the previous msg.

```
<div id="hidmsg" style="display:none"></div>

setInterval(function(){ 
    $('#hidmsg').load("get-messages.php?employee_id="+employee_id);

    $('#messagesBody').append($("#hidmsg").text());

    //$('#messagesBody').append($("#hidmsg").html());

}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is using a get request an option?

```
$.get('get-messages.php', {employee_id:employee_id}, function(data) { 
    $('#messagesBody').append(data);
});
```